# public interface BaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long>{ }

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface  BaseRepository extends  JpaRepository<Category, Long>{ }
```

Here I have a category Entity for the arguments ,I need to change a dynamaic entity ,in future catalogue entity,visit entity ,so managed that dynamically
any one help ???

Answer (score 0):

This `JpaRepository` interface is a generic class which the methods implemented out of the box by Spring rely on the types specified in the declaration class that is  : `<Category, Long>`.
Besides, specified generics are not designed to change neither at compile time nor at runtime.
So you want to declare and create a `Repository` for each entity to handle.

Now if it makes sense you could define a base repository interface to define common methods not dependent of the handled entity but you will not declare it such as :

```
public interface  BaseRepository extends  JpaRepository<Category, Long>{ }
```

but rather like that :

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{ }
```

And define subclass such as :

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends BaseRepository<Category, Long>{ }
```

Comment: public class CategoryService extends BaseService{
 public CategoryService(BaseRepository baseRepository) {super(baseRepository);}BaseService baseService=new BaseServic(baseRepository);
public Category save(Category category) {Category result = baseService.save(category);return result;}}public Category save(Category category) {Category result = baseService.save(category);return result;}
public interface CategoryRepository extends BaseRepository {}i need to dynamic entity like BaseEntity extends category
public interface  BaseRepository extends  JpaRepository<Category, Long>{}